# Was Spock ever called a mongrel in a Star Trek TV episode or movie?

Tags: star-trek, spock

This question is prompted by a question on English Language and Usage: [Can “mongrel” be used to refer to people?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/440343/can-mongrel-be-used-to-refer-to-people)  The OP of that ELU question is translating a fantasy novel into English.

My question is **not** whether this word is appropriate in the OP's (or any context) now (or ever), but whether, in fact, Mr. Spock was ever called a mongrel in a Star Trek TV episode or movie, and if so by whom and in what context.

I did find an interview with Leonard Nimoy in which Nimoy referred to Spock as a mongrel.  See [Nimoy Interview](http://www.leonardnimoy.de/index.php/interviews/1172-reflections-on-spock-) in which Nimoy says:

> What kind of person should I be? And Spock seemed to have a fix on
>   that. He had found a way to deal with those questions. In spite of the
>   fact that he was not really acceptable amongst humans totally because
>   he was strange, he was not totally acceptable among Vulcans because he
>   was part human, he was a mongrel.

Kirk called Spock a half-breed in [*What Are Little Girls Made Of*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/What_Are_Little_Girls_Made_Of%3F_(episode)), but Kirk was not in his right mind when he did so.

Comment: I don't recall any character ever referring to Spock in this way. Spock is referred to as a mongrel by a character (N'Mi) in William Leisner's 'Shocks of Adversity' (a non-canon novel), but I can't even find/think of this being used in the canon novels.

Comment: Kirk didn't call Spock a half breed.  The android duplicate of Kirk called Spock a half breed because real Kirk "programmed" the android to do so while being duplicated.  This was done so that Spock would notice something wrong and find out that Kirk had been replaced by an android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran a search through the scripts at http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/ and found no use of the word "mongrel" in any episode of the original *Star Trek*, *Star Trek:  The Animated Series*, or any of the films.

This also accords with my memory of the word not having been used.

"Half-breed," on the other hand, shows up in "This Side of Paradise," "Day of the Dove," and "What Are Little Girls Made Of?"